# Is there a way to create a video from images with a variable frame rate in Python?

Tags: python, video-processing

I have a folder filled with images labelled sequentially that I want to turn into a video. How would I get each image to take up a different length of the video?

I have seen a suggestion with ffmpeg, however it has a set framerate, with each image taking up the same length of time.

```py
def save():
    os.system("ffmpeg -r 1 -i img%01d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -y movie.mp4")
```

I need each image to take up a different length of time, as my video will end up similar to a slideshow, so only contains a few dozen images, not one image for every frame. How would I be able to create a video in this form?

Comment: I haven't used it, but [moviepy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) might help you.

Comment: If you're not attached to python (btw your question asks for python but uses ffmpeg ...), you can use gimp and make an animated gif. The framerate is either a constant (given when you save the file) or given for each layer.